# How to edit the debug console in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I recently downloaded Microsoft's Visual Studio as I heard it was a good IDE for C++. Everything works fine when I run a basic program, but the debug console looks cluttered to me. It has the message, "To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable `Tools`->`​Options`->`​Debugging`->`​Automatically close the console when debugging stops`." Is there any way to get rid of this?

[image: Here is a picture of what I mean]

Maybe I just have to get used to it, but there seems like there should be a way to remove it.

Comment: you want the debugger to close automatically after you done?

Comment: @BAS No I would like it to stay open, just have that long message about automatically closing it to be gone. It may not be possible and I may have to just get over it, but I figured I would at least ask y'all smart people first.

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger is one of the best in the business.  A simple message being displayed at the end of the debugging (not in the middle of debugging, but at the end) is a problem?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no it is not a problem. I was just wondering if I could get around having to see it every time.

Comment: The debugging mode is for debugging.  When you create a release program, you never see this message.  In any case, that is probably hard-coded in their debugging hook somewhere.  But seriously, I don't see how that message is such an issue to waste a lot of time on.

Comment: The message exists because previously the default behaviour was to automatically close the debug window. When the debug window closed, the output the new programmer spent so much time working to produce would go away with the window resulting in much panic and thousands (if not tens of thousands) of Stack Overflow questions that basically read, "AAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHH!" This is a much better alternative, even if the message is annoying.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove the message at the end.

Comment: @user4581301 that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If it is any consolation the message will probably go away in a few years when the window not closing becomes the expected behaviour. It's mostly there for the old folks who get a new copy of Visual Studio and want the old behaviour back because it's what they're used to. I have to admit that it's annoying when builds fail because a forgotten debug instance is still running in a window hidden under a few dozen other windows and the executable can't be written

Comment: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b35da83d-df0b-4ebb-9668-7bb9e98b6bdd/microsoft-visual-stupid-debug-console?forum=vsdebug]https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b35da83d-df0b-4ebb-9668-7bb9e98b6bdd/microsoft-visual-stupid-debug-console?forum=vsdebug